# What is going on with 書けている? What is Potential Form+ている?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, conjugations, potential-form

I'm having difficulty in understanding 書けている (initially observed from an answer to "[パソコンが　得意だ/わかる/上手だ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/6810/542)"). Also observed from [SPACEALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%91%E3%81%A6&ref=sa):

> - この小説は上手に書けている。
> - 最もよく書けている記事。
> - いくつかのスペルミスを除けば、その小論文はよく書けている。

I thought that the sentence would have been  この小説は上手に{書いている・書いてある}。instead.

**(Q1)** What is the difference between 書いている and 書けている? And what does 書けている mean?

**(Q2)** What is the grammatical composition of 書けている? Is it potential form+ている?

**(Q3)** Is this pattern of potential form+ている productive? I.e. can it be arbitrarily extended to other verbs with a similar result?

Comment: I suspect that this may be related to 出来た used in the sense of "completed".

Comment: 自発/spontaneous, right? I hope someone can write a proper answer on this. I don't think I can do it justice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is the potential form of 書く in the progressive.

These phrases are often used in the form 上手に/よく+[verb in potential form]. By itself, the potential form indicates that you are able to do something, and in combination with 上手に/よく, it means you did it well.

> よく読めた (praising a primary school kid on his 音読 reading out loud)
>
> 上手にできた etc.

The progressive is used for saying that the result is well written. `よく書けたね` would mean more the act of writing was well done, but says little about the result... There have been questions on the usage of the progressive tense with well-written answers. I'll try to find a link and post it here.