# Meaning of ようにできる

Tags: grammar

A sentence from Kanji in Context:

> 人にはそれぞれ長短があって、それで世の中はうまくいくようにできているのです。

I get that it means something like everyone has individual strengths and weaknesses, and thus the world can go smoothly. But what does ようにできる mean here? Is it being used as the potential form of ようにする, i.e. the world can be made to go smoothly?

Comment: Here's some example sentences for reference: http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A6&ref=sa

Comment: I think できている is only possible when it's *not* being used as a potential form of する, because I don't think potential forms can take ～ている.  (I'm not positive about when できている is permitted, though.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure potential forms can take ている 
Ex: この作文よく書けていますね。

Comment: @RodrigoPará Hmm, that's a good point.  But I suppose in that case it's no longer being used as a potential form.  I do see a [question about it](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6813/1478), which could probably use some elaboration...

Comment: @snailboat: I think the 〜ている form here is using the progressive form to convey a state (and is therefore consistent with the answer to the question you cite)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my intuition, ように binds stronger to the left, and できている means "accomplished". So ようにできる falls apart into these two.

人には People - それぞれ every one of them - 長短があって have strengths (and weaknesses) - それで therefore - 世の中は the world - うまくいく smooth-going - ように like such - できている become - therefore のです.

"Various people each have their strengths (and weaknesses), and this is what makes the world keep on turning."

The できている I put into "makes" here.

Comment: If I had noticed this answer, I wouldn't have written mine. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

> うまくいくようにできている

means something like "[thus] manages to go smoothly".

> But what does ようにできる mean here?

It would be more logical to view ように as connected with うまくいく, not with できている. うまくいくように is just "[in order] to go smoothly". できている means that the world actually manages to "go smoothly". できる would sound more like potential "the would can go smoothly" not specifying whether it actually does so.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed another answer, by Jens Jensen. Mine pretty much reiterates the same idea.